# Elasticsearch How to retrieve the maximum id

Tags: elasticsearch

How to retrieve the maximum id for one type index effectively?

Comment: Was your question not answered @proger2014? Please accept one of those

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [Max Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) (since 1.3) to get the maximum value of a given field in a document.

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search -d
  '{
    "aggs" : {
      "max_id" : {
        "max" : { 
          "field" : "id"
        }
      }
    },
    "size":0
  }'
```

Will return:

```
{
  "took":7,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards": {
    "total":6,
    "successful":6,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total":22,
    "max_score":0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "max_id": {
      "value": 27.0
    }
  }
}
```

In my case the maximum id is **27**.

Answer (score 6):

You want to get the top _id for a type?

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_id": "desc"
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

Comment: Deprecation: Loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of your documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled.

Comment: It returns, `Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [fields]`

Answer (score 3):

I tested this query on 1.4.2.  It should work with any mapping, because you are just sorting over the built in ElasticSearch ID.  If you are using your own id field it may or may not work depending on your mapping.  Try this and let me know how it works.

assuming your type is called `fruit`:

```
{
  'filter': {
    'type' : {
      'value' : 'fruit'
    }
  },
  'sort': {
    '_id': {
      'order': 'desc'
    }
  },
  'size': 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_uid"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
"size": 1,
"sort": [ { "_uid" : { "order" : "desc"} } ]
}
```